# Editing dropdown values without having to create a new dropdown every time

Tags: javascript, code.org

Within the code.org javascript editor for the applab, there is the ability to create a dropdown by creating a dropdown by:

```
dropdown('id', 'option1', 'option2', ...);
```

I would like to know if there is a way to edit the list, treating it something like an array:

```
remove('id', 'position');
```

and:

```
insert('id', 'position', 'item1', 'item2'...);
```

any help would be appreciated, as I can't find any way to do this in other places.

Comment: `...` is an operator (spread). Are you using "..." as an operator or just to show here that more code follows that you haven't posted?

Comment: The ... was just to show that you could add as many new items as you wanted, meaning that you could theoretically call many thousand new items in the dropdown. But this isn't actual code, I was just using this as a reference for what I want to try to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert dropdown to an array using **getProperty**. Then, edit the array, and convert it back to a dropdown with **setProperty**. Here's the code;

```
dropdown("id", "a", "b", "c");
function editDropdown() {
  var myDropdown = getProperty("id", "options");
  //add someting to your dropdown.
  appendItem(myDropdown, "e");
  //remove something from your dropdown.
  removeItem(myDropdown, "a");

  setProperty("id", "options", myDropdown);
  
}
editDropdown();
```